# Uso de old en Laravel recuerda siempre el campo del form

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

estoy haciendo un formulario de contacto con Laravel y estoy utilizando la función old, mi idea es que cuando las reglas de validación de un input se cumplan ese input se recuerde para que el usuario no lo tenga que volver a escribir y que si no se cumplan salte el mensaje de error y ese campo no lo recuerde, que se borre, que no se quede guardado.
En este mismo momento cumpla la regla de validación de ese input o no la cumpla cuando le doy a enviar el campo se queda guardado saltándome el mensaje de error en ese input. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo me guarde los datos de los inputs que están correctos?`

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" style="width: 70%" value="{{ old('nombre') }}"><br>
@if ($errors->has('nombre'))
<div class="text-danger"> {{ $errors->first('nombre') }} </div>
@endif

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
<input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="form-control"   value="{{ old('telefono') }}"><br>
@if ($errors->has('telefono'))
<div class="text-danger"> {{ $errors->first('telefono') }} </div>
@endif
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control"  value="{{ old('email') }}"><br>
@if ($errors->has('email'))
<div class="text-danger"> {{ $errors->first('email') }} </div>
@endif
</div> <button class="btn btn-dark btn_form" type="submit">Enviar</button>
```

`

Comment: intentaste con: `old('email') ?: ''`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Sí que probé pero me sigue sin funcionar